# How to solve 1st order, 2nd degree differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What would be the solution of :
$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2-x\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$
I need the working as well, please.

Comment: Solving for $$\frac{dy}{dx}$$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be useful if you include this in your questions, so that people know where you're stuck, and how to help you. If you want a hint, try differentiating the whole equation with respect to $x$.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643067/solution-of-differential-equation-left-fracdydx-right2-x-fracdydxy?rq=1